# Add records to an objece in Salesforce with PHP

Tags: php, form

I am trying to create a record in Salesforce Enterprise but I get an error message.

**The code:**

```
<?php

define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once ('userAuth.php');

try {
$mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
$mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

$sObject1 = new stdclass();
$sObject1->number__c = '20';
$sObject1->name__c = 'testupdateCity';
$sObject1->country__c = 'US';

$response = $mySforceConnection->update(array ($sObject1), 'nisaion_01__c');

print_r($response);

} catch (Exception $e) {
print_r($mySforceConnection->getLastRequest());
echo $e->faultstring;
}
?>
```

**The error:**

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Id not specified in an update call [statusCode] => MISSING_ARGUMENT ) ) [id] => [success] => ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use UPSERT call.

```
$response = $mySforceConnection->upsert(array ($sObject1), 'nisaion_01__c');
```

When you can UPDATE call, the ID field is required to uniquely identify which record to update.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the salesforce stack exchange community!

The problem is that you are using the wrong keyword to create a new record in salesforce.

You have to replace the keyword **update** with **create** in the following line:

```
$response = $mySforceConnection->update(array ($sObject1), 'nisaion_01__c');
```

The result

```
$response = $mySforceConnection->create(array ($sObject1), 'nisaion_01__c');
```

Comment: Thanks, Christian.
The Update works fine.
The "create" works but creates 3 records on each submit.  Any Ideas? Thanks. David.